# What should I mention in Signed-In User Case Action field

Tags: case, lightning-community, kokua

I am trying to create a case form in community template Kokua. I dragged the case form and it gives me the error

> To create cases, an action must be specified by the administrator

I don't know what to put in "Signed-in User Case Action"  field on the right hand side in Property Editor.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is the name of the *action* that is defined for the Case object which you want to use for the component.

From [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=rss_case_creation.htm&type=0):

> The **name of the action** that creates cases for authenticated users. Use the action layout editor for the case object in Salesforce setup to specify which fields to include in the layout. The **NewCase** action is a default in your Salesforce org.

If you face any error while defining the action, you may then like to take a look at this [knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000232310&type=1).

Answer (score 1):

You must put the api name of either the global action or the normal action inside that "Signed-in User Case Action" field.

Hope this helps!